# sprintf may be called with an invalid argument(null pointer). Using Polyspace bug finder

Tags: c, printf

I am using Polyspace Bug Finder with a C code.
I have a problem with sprintf. That is the code:

```
char* string1=NULL;
string1=(char*)malloc(snprintf(NULL,0,"%d",j)+1);
sprintf(string1,"%d",j);
```

Polyspace bug finder says:

> Invalid use of standard library routine (Impact High)
>   Standard function 'sprintf' may be called with an invalid argument.
>   First argument (string bufer) may be a null pointer.

Comment: malloc() can return NULL. You could handle that case. (and there is no need to cast malloc()s return value)

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question!! asprintf !!! This question can be closed